# Use pyspark countDistinct by another column with already grouped dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe that looks like this:

```
key  key2     category    ip_address  
1    a        desktop     111  
1    a        desktop     222  
1    b        desktop     333  
1    c        mobile      444  
2    d        cell        555
```

And I want to `groupBy` `key` to get the total number of unique `ip_addr`, along with the total number of unique `key_2`, and then the number of unique `ip_address` that was contributed by each `category` (assume the values in `category` are constant, so the values of `category` can only be [desktop, mobile, cell]).

So, I'm looking for a resulting dataframe like this:

```
key  num_ips      num_key2    num_desktop    num_mobile    num_cell      
1    4            3                 3              1             0
2    1            1                 0              0             0
```

I've been trying code like this, but the code for the `num_desktop`, `num_mobile`, `num_cell` isn't quite right.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df_agg = df.groupBy('key1') \
  .agg(F.countDistinct('ip_addr').alias('num_ips'), \
       F.countDistinct('key_2').alias('num_key2'), \
       F.countDistinct('ip_addr').where(F.col('category')=='desktop').alias('num_desktop'), \
       F.countDistinct('ip_addr').where(F.col('category')=='mobile').alias('num_mobile'), \
       F.countDistinct('ip_addr').where(F.col('category')=='cell').alias('num_cell')))
```

Do I have to do some type of nested `groupBy`, or maybe a `Window` function? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to split the dataframe and join them back for the desktop, mobile, and cell counts

```
df1 = df.groupBy('key') \
  .agg(F.countDistinct('ip_address').alias('num_ips'), \
       F.countDistinct('key2').alias('num_key2'))

de = df.filter(col("category")=="desktop").groupBy('key')\
    .agg(F.countDistinct('ip_address').alias('num_desktop')).withColumnRenamed("key", "key1")
dm = df.filter(col("category")=="mobile").groupBy('key')\
    .agg(F.countDistinct('ip_address').alias('num_mobile')).withColumnRenamed("key", "key1")
dc = df.filter(col("category")=="cell").groupBy('key')\
    .agg(F.countDistinct('ip_address').alias('num_cell')).withColumnRenamed("key", "key1")


join_df = df1.join(de, (df.key == de.key1), "left").drop("key1")\
    .join(dm, (df.key == dm.key1), "left").drop("key1")\
    .join(dc, (df.key == dc.key1), "left").drop("key1")\
    .fillna(0).drop('category', 'ip_address')
```

Output:

```
+---+-------+--------+-----------+----------+--------+                          
|key|num_ips|num_key2|num_desktop|num_mobile|num_cell|
+---+-------+--------+-----------+----------+--------+
|  1|      4|       3|          3|         1|       0|
|  2|      1|       1|          0|         0|       1|
+---+-------+--------+-----------+----------+--------+
```

Comment: I edited it to just use countDistinct() instead of windows functions.

Comment: Thanks! Yes I was wondering if there's an inherent difference computing-wise between doing separate groupby's instead of window functions